# Using SqlParameter for security with C# ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm converting the following C# markup to use SqlParameter (I'm new to SqlParameter) in order to enhance security:

```
public static void EmptyTable(string TableToEmpty)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE @prmTableToEmpty", conn))
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " + TableToEmpty, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prmTableToEmpty", TableToEmpty));
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

without the parameter use it works smoothly. However, with this syntax I get this exception:

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '@prmTableToEmpty'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2073550
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064508
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +215
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +178
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   pjsql.EmptyTable(String TableToEmpty) in c:\website\App_Code\mySqlClass.cs:67
   _Default.btnEmptyTheTable_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\website\Default.aspx.cs:83
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

both line numbers mentioned contains the throw; command.

I went through this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f844fc7(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f844fc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

and tried this alternative syntax: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

but with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: The `catch {throw;}` part is pointless and should be removed altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters may not be used in place of object names.

To enhance secutiry when dynamically substituting object names, use [`quotename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) (first execute a command `select quotename(@prmTableToEmpty)` using a parameter, then use the result of this command to build your `truncate` comand and execute it without parameters).

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    string sanitized_name;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select quotename(@prmTableToEmpty)", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prmTableToEmpty", TableToEmpty));
        sanitized_name = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " + sanitized_name, conn))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before getting to security, I do not understand why doesn't my markup work, and I would like to understand what the problem with my syntax is.

Comment: @Different111222 As I said, you cannot use parameters in place of object names. There is nothing to correct, it will not work. Object names must be provided in the same way as the reserved keywords. You cannot, for example, use a parameter instead of "TRUNCATE" to occasionally pass "CREATE" instead of "TRUNCATE".

Comment: Thanks, it works. But this is good to validate that it is about tables to look in the database for. What about more complex sanitation? This is an sql class I'm building. One of the methods is to create a table (too long to explain, basically it is a learning system) to a known table name passed to the method. What do I do there? how do I sanitize the text which should be the columns' description which is a single string for all columns together?

Comment: @Different111222 Without using a full-fledged SQL parser, you don't. If you're in a situation where you need to allow your users create a table with arbitrary structure, then you have to execute the user-supplied command under a database account which has permission to only create tables in a particular schema and nothing more.